# Is there any way to get the visual studio 2010 task list to work with database projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-dbpro

Is there any way to get the visual studio 2010 task list to work with database projects?

Comment: I use the task list in all Visual Studio 2010 projects including databases. What are the problems that you are having?

Comment: Are you referring to SQL Server Management Studio projects?